# How to remove an unwanted line in forest?

Tags: tikz-pgf, forest

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
    [TP
        [DP]
        [T'
        [T]
        [VP
        [DP]
        [V', name=node
        [V]
        [DP] ] ]]]
        \draw [red, thick, dotted] (node) --++(0em,+10ex) ellipse (1.5cm and 1cm);
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Hi, I am trying to draw an ellipse in an adjusted position with a `--++`
option in a forest tree, but I keep getting an unwanted line as shown in the picture attached. How can I draw a figure without that unwanted line?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
    [TP
        [DP]
        [T'
        [T]
        [VP
        [DP]
        [V', name=node
        [V]
        [DP] ] ]]]
        \draw [red, thick, dotted] (node) ++(0em,+10ex) ellipse (1.5cm and 1cm);
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Just replacing `--++` with `++`. The output:

[image: output pdf screenshot]

Then you can adjust position and shape of the ellipse *as usual* (package [`forest`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/forest) is based on TikZ).